# Python - Recognition Text image

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition

I have written this code with the premise of recognizing words in an image. This method finds some, but not all words as shown in the link.

My code is:

```
def methods_text_recognition_and_delete(self, path_floorplans, f, path_fw):

        image = cv2.imread(path_floorplans +f)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # grayscale
        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  # threshold
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
        dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations = 1)  # dilate
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)  # get contours

        # for each contour found, draw a rectangle around it on original image
        for contour in contours:
            # get rectangle bounding contour
            [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

            # discard areas that are too large
            if h > 300 and w > 300:
                continue

            # discard areas that are too small
            if h < 10 or w < 10:
                continue

            # draw rectangle around contour on original image
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 255), 2)

        # write original image with added contours to disk
        cv2.imwrite(path_fw + 'text_recognition_' + f, image)
```

Someone have an advice to improve the quality of this method?

Example of image: http://imageshack.com/a/img673/1598/QFaZ3i.png

Comment: Can you post an example output where it worked and one where it doesn't?

Comment: I think that i doesn't have enough rep for post an example of image!

Comment: How can you see not all word are recognized!

Comment: Maybe you should just try some advanced method like SWT? http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/149305/1509.pdf

Comment: Considering how simple your code is, I'm surprised it is able to get as much text as it does.  You can play with different structuring elements and different morphological operations but you will not be able to get all text from your example image just using 'findContours'.